# How to fail with a fatal error or similar?

Tags: javascript, fatal-error

Is it possible to terminate script on a certain condition with a specific error message? Exceptions are not an option, as they can be catched, thus avoiding termination.

**Update:**

I'd prefer the universal approach, but if there's none, then it's for the in-browser JavaScript. Error should be silent, and the error message should only go into the browser error log.

Comment: Is your script running in a browser ? To whom is intended your error message if you don't want it to be catchable ? Maybe you should make your question less vague.

Comment: @dystroy, sorry for the confusion, I updated the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I only managed to accomplish this through the following ugly workaround:

```
var failWithFatalError; // A non-existent function
console.error (message + ' in ' + homebrewStackTraceFunction());
failWithFatalError();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your code is inside a try statement, and you are looking for a way to stop it for certain errors, then I think you are looking for the finally block:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FStatements#The_finally_Block

From that site (and editing the annoying `alert()` for `console.log()`) you can find this example:

```
function f() {
    try {
        console.log(0);
        throw "bogus";
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(1);
        return true; // this return statement is suspended until finally block has completed
        console.log(2); // not reachable
    } finally {
        console.log(3);
        return false; // overwrites the previous "return"
        console.log(4); // not reachable
    }
    // "return false" is executed now

    console.log(5); // not reachable
}
f(); // alerts 0, 1, 3; returns false
```

Comment: But I don't need to continue execution, and I don't see how the `finally` helps me. I only need the script to die, there and then.

Comment: Notice that the last console.log(5) is not executed in this example, so it means that the process dies here once the non-catched exception is launched. This happens because the last return false; in the finally statement. This try statement is inside the function so it stop only the function, but if you place it around the script it will stop the script whenever you launch an uncatched exception.